# SQL Server and index and null parameters

Tags: t-sql, indexing

I have the below stored procedure that run against 2,304,697 records :

```
@startdate DATETIME NULL,
@enddate DATETIME NULL,
@drilldown VARCHAR(20) NULL

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime) as Year,
        MAX(DATENAME(MONTH, ReceivingTime)) AS Month, 
        ProductionLocation,
        CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*) * 100) OVER (PARTITION BY  DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime), MONTH(ReceivingTime)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS TotalsByMonth,
        CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*) * 100) OVER (PARTITION BY  DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS TotalsByYear
    FROM 
        Jobs_analytics
    WHERE 
        ProductionLocation IS NOT NULL 
        AND ((ReceivingTime BETWEEN dbo.cleanStartDate(@startdate) AND dbo.cleanEndDate(@enddate)) 
             AND @startdate IS NULL) 
        OR ((YEAR(ReceivingTime) = @drilldown) AND @drilldown IS NULL)
    GROUP BY   
        DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime), 
        DATEPART(MONTH, ReceivingTime), ProductionLocation
    ORDER BY  
        DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime),
        DATEPART(MONTH,  ReceivingTime)
```

The query works well in that it returns a data set in about 8 seconds. But I like to get the speed better So I added the below index:

```
CREATE INDEX RecDateTime
ON Jobs_analytics(RecDateTime, ProductionLocation)
go
```

however that really didn't improve anything. So I ran the execution plan and I notice that the my index is being used and the cost was 35% and my sort was at 6%.

[image]

So I reworked my where clause from this:

```
WHERE ProductionLocation IS NOT NULL AND  
     ((ReceivingTime BETWEEN dbo.cleanStartDate(@startdate) and dbo.cleanEndDate(@enddate) ) AND @drilldown IS NULL) 
    OR ((YEAR(ReceivingTime) = @drilldown) AND @startdate IS NULL)
```

to this:

```
WHERE ProductionLocation IS NOT NULL AND  
 ReceivingTime BETWEEN dbo.cleanStartDate('2018-07-01') and dbo.cleanEndDate('2019-08-25')
```

and I got the query to run in a second. As you can see there is no more filter and the cost on the cluster is at 3%..( something I did not realize)

[image]

The NULL parameter checks are for a report that sometimes will have null values set. so I don't have to maintain two stored procedures. I can write a second stored procedure and just remove the where clause items but I rather not. is there any index or changes to my query that anyone could suggest that might help

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if anyone comes across this this is what I found out:

1. I was testing the wrong parameter for null values within the OR
   clause.
2. I have function that adds the hh:mm:ss to a date that was also
   causing me problem.
3. I fixed both those items and the query runs in about a second.